# VueJS / Vuex App - Validate JWT Token USED for Authentication

Tags: authentication, vue.js, jwt, vuex, vue-router

I have a VueJS App, using Vuex & Vue Router.
I have 3 components (which are also pages): Home, Login and a Protected Page which requires one to be authenticated.

The login page make a POST call to the backend API which returns a token if the credentials are valid.

```
  methods: {
    sendCredentials: function() {
      const { email, password } = this
      this.$store.dispatch(AUTH_REQUEST, {email, password})
      .then(() => {
          this.$router.push('/')
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err.response));
    }
  }
```

Here is the related action:

```
actions: {
    [AUTH_REQUEST]: ({ commit, dispatch }, user) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            commit(AUTH_REQUEST);
            axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/login', user)
                .then((resp) => {
                    const token = resp.data.token;
                    localStorage.setItem('userToken', token);
                    commit(AUTH_LOGIN, token);
                    resolve(resp);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    commit(AUTH_ERROR, err);
                    localStorage.removeItem('userToken');
                    reject(err);
                })

        });
    }
```

I have used navigation guard to block access to the protected page if the user is not logged in.

This is actually working: When I go the protected page, I'm asked to log in. When I use the rights credentials, I'm able to access the protected page.

I have yet a huge bug: When I put any random string on the localStorage as the userToken, I can access the protected page...

How to prevent that ?

The initial state is defined as below:

```
state: {
    token: localStorage.getItem('userToken') || '',
},
```

Is there a way to validate the userToken which I get through the localStorage when I set up the initial state of token ?

Comment: Could you use cookies to store your token instead of local storage?

Comment: @Andrew1325 I can use cookie but don't we have the same issue ? I can create the cookie with document.cookie="userToken=1234".

Comment: You need to store the token in your api also and validate it. If anything is client side only it is always vulnerable. Cookies allow you to pass header information to the server which local storage doesn't.

Comment: I'm using express-jwt to validate the cookie on the back-end.
I have some endpoints that can be reached only if the token is valid. For the restricted routes in the client app, I don't understand how to proceed as what I'm checking is only if I have a token.
How can I validate the token through the API when I initiate my state then ?

Comment: I use nuxt and call the verification through nuxtServerInit but in vue you should still be able to call a validation method with beforeMount. Although this isn't called during SSR so if your doing that you'd need something else.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but since you're using navigation guards that would mean you're protecting your app on the clients end, meaning you need a proper validation of the token in the navigation guard as well. Show us your Router navigation guard, that's where you're probably messing up, e.g. just checking if token is set instead of actually verifying that it's a correct token before continuing, or accidentally having added `next()` in the wrong place, like, `if(correct){next()}else{next()}` instead of `next({name: 'Home'})`

Comment: @Andrew1325 Nuxt seems to be some interesting things, I'll check that!

Comment: @SimonHyll you're right Simon, I have a boolean that only check if the token is set. I have no way of verifiying it without making a call to the API.. but it's async so I can't do it when I initiate my state, right?

Comment: Navigation guards are Promise based. That's why you have to call `next()` for it to continue. Just add the API call in your navigation call and in the `then()` you call `next()`. And yes you can use e.g. Vuex inside your Router, just import your `store.js` file where you create the Router and you'll have the Vuex store available to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been wondering the same thing a while ago. What I ended up with is to check the token against your backend on initial loading of your page. If the token is valid you commit it to Vuex, if the token is invalid, you delete everyting from localStorage.

This leads to the outcome where someone hypothetically could replace the token after initial load with their own invalid token, but if the clientside token is already validated, what would be the point? If you want to secure against this scenario as well you could apply the same logic in your navigation guard. So not just check for a token, but validate the token against your backend on each route change and clear localStorage if invalid. I think this will come at a performance disadvantage though due to the extra API call.

Comment: I finally ended by doing that verification call on my main.js It's perfectly working now, thanks!